# Does C++20's 'requires' keyword slow your program?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Consider this class:

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    std::string last;
    int age;
    
public:
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    Person(T1&& name, T2&& last, int age) noexcept
        : name(std::forward<T1>(name))
        , last(std::forward<T2>(last))
        , age(age)
    {}

    Person(const Person& other) noexcept            = default;
    Person(Person&& old) noexcept                   = default;
    Person& operator=(const Person& other) noexcept = default;
    Person& operator=(Person&& old) noexcept        = default;
};
```

Would you rewrite the constructor's template with... ? Would it be faster?

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> requires (
    std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T1>, std::string> &&
    std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T2>, std::string>
)
```

And another question just cause... Could I make these constructors `constexpr`? If so, would it be more efficient?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/. Words like "more efficient" and "faster" are not objective metrics. Please define them very specifically and show which benchmarks you're using to measure speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does C++20's 'requires' keyword slow your program?

No, it specifies a constant expression on template parameters that evaluate a requirement - or in a template declaration, specifies an associated constraint.

Template parameters (and constraints) must be compile time constants by nature and won't affect the speed of your compiled program.

Comment: what about the making the constructors `constexpr`?

Comment: @Karlos If adding `constexpr` is the only change, it will not affect the speed either.